# How to inject beequeue job in a controller in NESTJS

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am new to NestJS, and I am trying to implement a bee queue job. I have a method in my controller where I trigger the bee queue job.

This the method in my controller:

```
 @Get('clickToCallStatusCallBack')
  clickToCallStatusCallBack(@Query() callData: CDRModels){
    console.log('CLICK TO CALL STATUS CALL BACK API', callData);

    jobQueue.createJob(callData).save();

    new ClickToCallJob(this._freeswitchCallSystemService).trigger(callData);

    return "Successfully submitted to job queue";
  }
```

This is my code for ClickToCallJob :

```
export class ClickToCallJob implements IBeeQueueJob<any>{

    constructor(
        private readonly _freeswitchCallSystemService: FreeswitchCallSystemService
    ){}

    trigger(parameter: any) {
        jobQueue.process((job, done) => {

            console.log('jobid', job.id);
            console.log('result', job.data);
            done(null, job.id);
        });

        jobQueue.on('succeeded', (job,result) => {
            console.log('success');
        })
    }
}
```

This is the interface :

```
export interface IBeeQueueJob<T>{
    trigger(parameter: T);
}
```

Instead of calling the job like this:

```
new ClickToCallJob(this._freeswitchCallSystemService).trigger(callData);
```

Is there any possible way to inject a job in a controller, and register it to the module?

Thanks in advance!